# Variable in ejs partial not defined, even though it is?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So I'm following this youtube tutorial, and it's gotten to a part where I should display an error message using an ejs partial. followed the tutorial to a T, but i get this error:

```
ReferenceError: C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\views\layouts\layout.ejs:11
    9| <body>

    10|     <%- include('../partials/header.ejs') %>

 >> 11|     <%- include('../partials/err_msg.ejs') %>

    12|     <%- body %>

    13| </body>

    14| </html>

C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\views\partials\err_msg.ejs:1
 >> 1| <%= errorMessage %>

errorMessage is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), <anonymous>:10:26)
    at err_msg (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at include (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:701:39)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), <anonymous>:15:17)
    at layout (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\PATH\mongo_db_app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
```

The err_msg.ejs contains one line, namely `<%= errorMessage %>`. The layout file in which it is used is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mybrary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%- include('../partials/header.ejs') %>
    <%- include('../partials/err_msg.ejs') %>
    <%- body %>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code block where `errorMessage` is coming from:

```js
router.post('/', (req,res) => {
    const author = new Author({
        name: req.body.name
    })
    author.save((err, newAuthor) => {
        if (err){
            res.render('authors/new', {
                author: author,
                errorMessage: 'Error creating author'
            })
        } else {
            //res.redirect(`authors/${newAuthor.id}`)
            res.redirect(`authors`)
        }
    })
})
```

For more info, here is the github repo: https://github.com/DragosSaviour/Mybrary

Can someone help me understand/solve this problem?

EDIT: I have tried doing

```
<%if (errorMessage) { %>
    <%= errorMessage %>
<% } %>
```

the result remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `errorMessage` exits, if it's not undefined with `typeof` (your attempt checks if it's *truthy*, which is why it fails, because it doesn't exist).

Try this:

```
<%if (typeof errorMessage != "undefined") { %>
    <%= errorMessage %>
<% } %>
```